# Unable to deserialize as json string using newtonsoft

Tags: c#, json.net

The repeating portion of my JSON string is not being deserialized when I executed this command:

```
UsageAndDemand.UsageAndDemandResponse UsgDmdResp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UsageAndDemand.UsageAndDemandResponse>(jsonString);
```

That code is working correctly in another program of mine that uses a different object

Here is my code:

```
downloadString = 
"http://dp72m.someserver.com:9090/ws/simple/queryMeterUsage?";
downloadString += "startdate=" + startDate + "&enddate=" + endDate + 
"&profile=" + profile + "&metric=";
downloadString += metric;
downloadString += "&sdp=" + sdp + "&zip=" + zipCode + "&metertype=" + 
meterType;


using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    jsonString = client.DownloadString(downloadString);
}

UsageAndDemand.UsageAndDemandResponse UsgDmdResp = 
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UsageAndDemand.UsageAndDemandResponse> 
(jsonString);
if (UsgDmdResp.ResponseCode == 0)
{
    PopulateGraph(UsgDmdResp);
```

Class Definition:

```
public class UsageAndDemand
{

}
public UsageAndDemand()
{
    //
    // TODO: Add constructor logic here
    //
}

public class MeterUsageDemand
{
    [JsonProperty("UsageDate", NullValueHandling =
        NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public String UsageDate { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("KwhUsed", NullValueHandling =
        NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public float KwhUsed { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("HighTemp", NullValueHandling =
        NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public float MaxTemp { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("LowTemp", NullValueHandling =
        NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public float MinTemp { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("KwDemand", NullValueHandling =
        NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public float KwDemand { get; set; }
}

public class UsageAndDemandResponse
{
    public int ResponseCode { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public List<MeterUsageDemand> MeterUsageDemand { get; set; }
}
```

JSON string to deserialize:

```
{
"ResponseCode" : 0,
"Message" : "Success",
"UsageAndDemand" : [
{
  "UsageDate" : "2018-08-01",
  "KwhUsed" : 624.27,
  "HighTemp" : 93.00,
  "LowTemp" : 70.00,
  "KwDemand" : 1.21
},
{
  "UsageDate" : "2018-09-01",
  "KwhUsed" : 777.75,
  "HighTemp" : 93.00,
  "LowTemp" : 68.00,
  "KwDemand" : 1.12
},
{
  "UsageDate" : "2018-10-01",
  "KwhUsed" : 815.52,
  "HighTemp" : 91.00,
  "LowTemp" : 50.00,
  "KwDemand" : 1.28
},
{
  "UsageDate" : "2018-11-01",
  "KwhUsed" : 844.68,
  "HighTemp" : 87.00,
  "LowTemp" : 36.00,
  "KwDemand" : 1.3
},
{
  "UsageDate" : "2018-12-01",
  "KwhUsed" : 800.8,
  "HighTemp" : 81.00,
  "LowTemp" : 41.00,
  "KwDemand" : 1.27
},
{
  "UsageDate" : "2019-01-01",
  "KwhUsed" : 27.8,
  "KwDemand" : 1.22
}
]
}
```

Walking it thru the debugger in VS2015, if I inspect the deserialized object (UsgDmdResp) I can see the `ResponseCode` is equal to 0 and the message says "success" but the repeating portion (of the JSON string) is null. As I mentioned above, the very code is working in another page that deserializes to a slightly different object class.

Can anyone see why my repeating values are null?

Comment: `UsageAndDemand` in JSON does not match `MeterUsageDemand` in your C# class

Answer (score 5):

Wrong property name `MeterUsageDemand` should be `UsageAndDemand`

```
public class UsageAndDemandResponse
{
    public int ResponseCode { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("UsageAndDemand", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public List<MeterUsageDemand> MeterUsageDemand { get; set; }
}
```

or

```
public class UsageAndDemandResponse
{
    public int ResponseCode { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public List<MeterUsageDemand> UsageAndDemand{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hey Guys, thanks so much for the answers.  The one that I said was working in another page using a different class.....guess I just got lucky with my property names.  Thanks again.